# ASP.Net Core Identity Question marks instead of letters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, razor-pages

The thing is that when I try to use Russian letters in Identity pre-made pages they just doesn't work. They look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZlYg.png). I'm using Razor Pages btw.

This is _LoginPartial.cshtml  for example

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using AIProbe0.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out Выйти</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-page="/Account/Register">Registration</a></li>
        <li><a asp-page="/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

I tried to use `<meta charset="utf-8" />` and `<meta charset="Windows-1251" />,` but it didn't help at all. My own pages are allright. 
Tried to find the reason, but failed. How can I make Identity pages see Russian letters?

Comment: Do the Cyrillic script characters show correctly in debugging?  In the example above it appears hardcoded.  Also confirm that `Content-Type` header is set to "text/html; charset=utf-8".

Comment: @MarkG No, they don't show correctly in debugging. I tried to set enctype="text/plain" in form, but it didn't help. And tried to add <meta Content-Type="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />, but it didnt help either. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Allright, I don't know is it a bug or something, but Visual Studio creates some ASP.NET Core pages witch ANSI-encoding and not with UTF-8. The only solution I found is to manually change file's encoding with NotePad++. At least it's not hard, only takes time.
[Works fine, though.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVI9Y.png)